# I cannot use a function that is defined in another namespace in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I am using autoloading to load files defined with namespaces. I have defined a redirect function inside of a namespace:

```php
<?php
namespace sirJuni\Framework\Helper;

function redirect($url) {
    header("Location: $url");
}

?>
```

The project structure is like:

```
- sirJuni\
    - src\
        - Helper\
            - Functions.php // where the function is defined
```

Then what i am trying to do is use autoloading to load this file and use the redirect function:

```php
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use function sirJuni\Framework\Helper\redirect;

redirect("hello/hi");
?>
```

This gives an error : call to undefined function
But if i try to use other classes which are defined in the above project `sirJuni` i can use them without an issue. It only happens when i try to use a function from another namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP currently has no autoloading for functions. Your use statement only reference the namespaced name of the function. You still need to manually include the Functions.php so you can use functions in it.